# Using parentheses as delimiter in re or str.split() python

Tags: python

I am trying to split a string such as:  `add(ten)sub(one)`  into `add(ten) sub(one)`.
I can't figure out how to match the close parentheses.  I have used `re.sub(r'\\)', '\\) ')` and every variation of escaping the parentheses,I can think of.  It is hard to tell in this font but I am trying to add a space between these commands so I can split it into a list later.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want the output to be the string `"add(ten) sub(one)"`, or the list `["add(ten)", "sub(one)"]`, or something else? You can prevent SO from mis-formatting your code by enclosing it in [backticks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick). (the character below the tilde)

Comment: just adding the space would be great, as I use split in another line to get the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to escape `)` in the replacement string, `)` has a special a special meaning only in the regex pattern so it needs to be escaped there in order to match it in the string, but in normal string it can be used as is.

```
>>> strs = "add(ten)sub(one)"
>>> re.sub(r'\)(?=\S)',r') ', strs)
'add(ten) sub(one)'
```

As @StevenRumbalski pointed out in comments the above operation can be simply done using `str.replace` and `str.rstrip`:

```
>>> strs.replace(')',') ').strip()
'add(ten) sub(one)'
```

Comment: This replacement is simple enough to not need a regex `strs = strs.replace(')',') ')`.  Add a `.strip()` at the end if you want to get rid of the final space.

Comment: this doesn't work in my 3.3.2 shell, I get the same string with no space.

Comment: @user2755466:  Are you assigning the result back to your variable name?  If not, you will lose the result as strings in Python are immutable.

Comment: I guess that was it Steve, but I dont know why I had to assign it to a new string in IDLE but not in the interpreter...

Comment: @user2755466 http://ideone.com/UTmREc, interpreter automatically echoes the output of a command, but in IDLE you need to assign the result to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = ')'
my_str = 'add(ten)sub(one)'
result = [t+d for t in my_str.split(d) if len(t) > 0]
```

result = ['add(ten)','sub(one)']

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of all substrings

```
import re

a = 'add(ten)sub(one)'
print [ b for b in re.findall('(.+?\(.+?\))', a) ]
```

Output:

```
['add(ten)', 'sub(one)']
```